# Setting vertical scan angles in visibility analysis (viewshed) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis, viewshed, angles

Is it possible, doing a visibility analysis (viewshed) in QGIS, to set a vertical angle of search from the observer points?

In [ArcGIS Pro viewshed](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/viewshed-global-function.htm), there are the `vertical upper angle` and `vertical lower angle` parameters. In [Global Mapper viewshed](https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/knowledgebase/global-mapper-21-1/View_Shed_Tool.htm), it is possible to set angles in the tool dialog, 'Receiver Elevation' section.

In QGIS, I could not find such option in the [Visibility Analysis plugin](http://www.zoran-cuckovic.from.hr/QGIS-visibility-analysis/help_qgis3.html) (version 1.2; 24-apr-2020) and in the [r.viewshed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.viewshed.html) tool from GRASS ([gdal_viewshed](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_viewshed.html) does not have it either).

I am aware about the `target_elevation` parameter (which is the one I am currently using), but it is a different (substitute or complementary) method from setting a vertical angle range from the observer view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using the QGIS [Visibility Analysis plugin](http://www.zoran-cuckovic.from.hr/QGIS-visibility-analysis/help_qgis3.html) since version 1.3 (18-dec-2020).

The parameters are `Upper angle mask` and `Lower angle mask` available in the `Create Viewpoints` tool.

> Upper/lower angle determines the maximum/minimum angle of vision. Areas above/below these values will be excluded, that is, registered as not visible. Horizontal (eye) level is at 0 degrees, angles below the hor. level can reach up to -90 degrees, and above the hor. level up to +90 deg. The specified lower angle has to be smaller than the upper angle.

[image]